# jQuery disable click on other divs once one is selected then make the class clickable again on next set

Tags: jquery

This is basically a multiple choice test page.
Each div class .choice contains an answer (choice 1-5 etc).

```
$('.choice').click(function () {
        checkAnswer(this.id, this.title);
});
```

and then the checkAnswer displays a correct or incorrect message and scrolls to the next set of questions.  The problem is I want them to only click one choice then when the "next" link appears to have the next set of answer divs to be clickable again.

unbind bind on off add/remove class something something
Here's the HTML

```
                        <div class="wrap-choices">
                            <div id="1a" title="Q1" class="choice">
                                <p>
                                    <span>A. </span>Car
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="1b" title="Q1" class="choice">
                                <p>
                                    <span>B. </span>Cat
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="1c" title="Q1" class="choice">
                                <p>
                                    <span>C. </span>Cow
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="1d" title="Q1" class="choice">
                                <p>
                                    <span>D. </span>All of the above
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

here's the portion for checking the answer in array

```
function checkAnswer(answerID,qNumber) {

var arr = ['1d', '2c', '3d', '4b'];
var correct = $.inArray(answerID, arr);
//display an incorrect or correct popup
if (correct > -1) {
    $('.' + qNumber + ' .correct').show();

} else {
    $('.' + qNumber + ' .incorrect').show();
}
//add code to disable clicking any other div here
$('.next').show();
//and then when clicking on that next image, the click is enabled again for those divs
};
```

Comment: Could you post your markup? I need to know your html structure as well as what type of inputs you're using in order to help you.

Comment: Where is the "next" link coming from, where's the code that scrolls, and what do the questions look like? I'm guessing something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJL7L/), but without more info it's hard to help ?

Comment: i've added additional info.  basically when the .next image appears, clicking on that will move the div up and expose another set of question and answers.

Comment: thank you all.  I ended up just using this:
on the checkAnswer
 $('.choice').attr('onClick', '');
and then on the next
 $('.choice').attr('onClick','checkAnswer(this.id,this.title)');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="q-1" class="question">
        <p>Question?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="answer-1" value="A" />A
        <input type="radio" name="answer-1" value="B" />B
        <input type="radio" name="answer-1" value="C" />C
        <input type="radio" name="answer-1" value="D" />D
        <p><a href="#q-2">Next</a></p>

    </div>
    <div id="q-2" class="question">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="q-3" class="question">
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.question input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    // checkAnswer(this.id, this.title);
    // You may want to add a title attribute and use this.parentNode.id instead

    // The code below randomly decides if it's true or false, FOR TESTING ONLY
    var check = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 ); 
    $(this).nextAll('p').prepend(check ? 'correct ' : 'incorrect ').fadeIn();    

    $(this).siblings('input[type="radio"]').addBack().prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parent().next().find('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

CSS:

```
.question p{display:none}
.question p:first-child{display:block;}
```

I used a number of jQuery functions to keep the code as small as possible. Please see below for links to a few useful documentation pages:

- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll)
- [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)
- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R9MCT/2/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! instead of radio buttons though...any possibility of click events on divs?  I basically need to disable the div or the click and have it clickable again.  I will check those functions to see if they can be used..

Comment: although I did not end up using this approach I can see how it would have worked with radio buttons.  Thank you for the thorough answer and if you have any advice on my decision to just change the onClick attr (as far as best practice etc.)...would appreciate it.